# Windows Forms - Allowing the user to select text in a RichTextBox charcater by character (disabling word automatic selection)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a hex editor using Windows Forms, and I've made a RichTextBox which displays the ASCII representation of the hex data, like this:

[image: ASCII representation of the data]

I want the user to be able to select what's in the text box character by character, but the control changes the selection automatically so it starts and ends on word boundaries.

For example, in the image above, selecting from `May` to `J` (first letter of June) will select `May JuneJulyAug` instead of just `May J`. It appears that it is impossible for the user to *only* select `May J`.

Is there any way to turn off this automatic selection? I've set `AutoWordSelection` to false, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: The property is set only when the handle is already created, because it's supposed to be the default behavior. You can simply call `CreateControl()` right after you have created the instance: `var rtb = new RichTextBox(); rtb.CreateControl(); (...) [Container].Controls.Add(rtb); rtb.AutoWordSelection = false;`. Otherwise, you'll have to wait until the Handle is created, in `Form.Load()` you sure about that (but maybe you don't want to clutter it up). You can use custom controls and override `OnHandleCreated`.

Comment: Btw, the property is decorated with `[DefaultValue(false)]`, so the property value is not serialized when set in the designer. Then it's reset in the `OnHandleCreated` override, but before calling `base.OnHandleCreated(e);`...